# Comparison question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, self-learning

U is concave and increasing function

I know that

$$w-t_n\ge 1/2$$

$$U(w-t_a)\ge U(1/2)$$

How can I compare $t_a$ and $t_n$

All $w>t_i>0$ for all i=n,a.

Comment: What does the "I know that" part mean?

Comment: Shifting the axes preserves both monotonicity and convexity, so it can be assumed WLOG that $\,t_n = 0\,$, $\,U(1/2)=0\,$, but I don't think there is enough information to answer the question.